# Omni Supervisor Tab - Under Agent Tab can we remove "change Status" Link

Tags: service-cloud-console, omni-supervisor, sevice

[image]

Can we deactivate or Remove the "Change status" Link anyway ? If not, Do anything have been documented anywhere in salesforce. Please share.

Answer (score 1):

Presently, there is no way to remove the "Change status" action

Found a similar Idea already posted on Idea exchange.

Permission to change presence configuration within the Omni supervisor: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpRXUAZ/permission-to-change-presence-configuration-within-the-omni-supervisor